# Update elements situated in sequential index inside List in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of `byte` in which I want to update certain elements. The list `allIntNumbers` contains lots of data, however, I just want to update certain elements. These elements are situated in a sequential index. Below is the sample code:

```
List<byte> allIntNumbers = new List<byte>();
byte[] myIntBytes = new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3}; //4 bytes
allIntNumbers[0] = myIntBytes[0]; allIntNumbers[1] = myIntBytes[1];
allIntNumbers[2] = myIntBytes[2]; allIntNumbers[3] = myIntBytes[3];
```

In the example above, list `allIntNumbers` contains many elements but now shown in the code snippet above. I wanted to change first 4 elements of `allIntNumbers`. So I assigned each element by accessing the index.

However, I believe there should be a better way to do the same. PS: I found certain similar questions in SO but all of them are related to custom objects such as their own class i.e. Person etc. I am not sure if following those questions is better way or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple `for` loop, if they are one-to-one

```
var allIntNumbers = new List<byte>();
var myIntBytes = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; //4 bytes

for (var i = 0; i < myIntBytes.Length; i++)
{
   allIntNumbers[i] = myIntBytes[i];
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Agree with you. This is almost similar to what I have posted above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RemoveRange() and InsertRange() method for this purpose.

```
Listvar.RemoveRange(index,count);
Listvar.InsertRange(index, anotherList);
```

Comment: This seems cleaner. However how about the performance? I would prefer the quicker way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allIntNumbers = new List<byte>(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
var myIntBytes = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; //4 bytes

Enumerable.Range(0, 4) //starting index and count
    .Select((n, index) => allIntNumbers[index] = myIntBytes[index])
    .Any();
```

`Any` just need to iterate `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I am not sure about it. I will check it later. By the way, how is the performance of this code? I prefer the faster way.

Comment: @RaviJoshi how many billions of such operations do you have if you talk about perfomance? The fastest way you wrote in question, next is for loop. Other are similar

Comment: Okay. How to modify the code if the index of `allIntNumbers` is non-zero say 5.

Comment: @RaviJoshi `Enumerable.Range(0, 4)` change `0` to `5`